# What should I do with a question that has been edited, but has an answer to it in its old phrasing?

Tags: discussion

I have asked [a question](https://askubuntu.com/q/879472/181242) about how to make keyboard layout switching permanent in `awesome` window manager. Later, when I realised that my issue is not specific to any window manager, I edited it to become about keyboard layout indicator in `awesome` WM.

However, the question have already received an answer to it, in its old phrasing.

Now, what should I do with the question? I would like to initiate a bounty for it, but would it be right to do, given the situation?

Answer (score 4):

Suggest an edit to the answer that "This answer was written against a previous revision of the question, and is kept here for historical purposes" or similar.

You'd use this code, basically, for the above message:

```
> This answer was written against a previous revision of the question, and is kept here for historical purposes.
```

which would give us something like this:

> This answer was written against a previous revision of the question, and is kept here for historical purposes.